# How increase response time in zabbix trigger?

Tags: zabbix

In my zabbix-server i have problem "High ICMP ping response time"

[here is screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtTAj.png)
So, average value of ping is abput 250 ms but it does not matter.

so, how can i increase value of this trigger for example to 500 ms ?

I mean if my ping value would be more then 500, just then  zabbix will alert me.

now my trigger is:

```
{Template Module ICMP Ping:icmppingsec.avg(5m)}>
{$ICMP_RESPONSE_TIME_WARN}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This trigger uses a so called [user macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/macros/usermacros) - think of them as variables. This can be changed either in the host or template properties, the "Macros" tab.

If you want to modify it for all hosts using this template, change the value in the template. If you want to customise it on a specific host only, change the value for that host.